# Can not call Selector of Map SVG (Wordpress map plugin) when clicked

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-selectors, selector, mapsvg

I am working on a Wordpress website with a MapSVG plugin. Here it is:http://www.wordpressdemo7.mozaikdesign.fr/

My client want to open specific tab bellow when click on an area of the map. For example, when click on Kalimantan area, the tab Kalimantan will be open.

The problem is I can not select the clicked area. I used the code bellow but no luck.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      jQuery("a[href$=#tanjung]").click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#tabbed-nav").data('zozoTabs').select(4);
      });
});
```

So, can anyone help me out of this problem? Thank you and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from plugin's author. You have to put it into **onClick** event handler in **javaScript** tab inside of MapSVG control panel:

```
function(){
  var regionID = this.id;
  if (regionID == "Kalimantan"){  
     jQuery("#tabbed-nav").data('zozoTabs').select(4);
  }
}
```